# Firestore - get large collection and parse. Request is aborted

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've had a look around but can't find an obvious solution.

I have a collection with 130k documents. I need to export these as a CSV file. (The CSV part I have sorted I think).

My code works fine with smaller collection but when trying it on the 130k documents in a collection it hangs and I get "Request Aborted". What would be the best way to handle this?

My code:

```
db.collection("games")
.doc(req.params.docid)
.collection("players")
.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
  console.log("On Snapshot")
  snapshot.docs.forEach(data => {

    const doc = data.data();

    downloadArray.push(doc);

  });

  jsonexport(downloadArray, function(err, csv) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    fs.writeFile("out.csv", csv, function() {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../out.csv"), err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I'm trying out pagination as suggested, however I'm having trouble understanding how to keep calling the next batch until the loop is done, as sometimes I won't know the collection size, and querying such a large collection size takes over 1-2 minutes.

```
 let first = db
      .collection("games")
      .doc(req.params.docid)
      .collection("players")
      .orderBy("uid")
      .limit(500);

    let paginate = first.get().then(snapshot => {
      // ...
      snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data());
      });

      // Get the last document
      let last = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];

      // Construct a new query starting at this document.
      let next = db
        .collection("games")
        .doc(req.params.docid)
        .collection("players")
        .orderBy("uid")
        .startAfter(last.data())
        .limit(500);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [paginate your query with cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) to reduce the size of the result set to something more manageable, and keep paging forward until the collection is fully iterated.

Also, you will want to use [get()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#get) instead of onSnapshot(), as an export process is probably not interested in receiving updates for any document in the set that might be added, changed, or deleted.

Comment: Using the .limit() function? Most of these examples I've seen are pretty low limits. I wonder how high I can push it.

Comment: Yes, you will want to use a limit, and also be reasonable about how much memory you want to use for a single page.

Comment: I've added onto my question above, do you perhaps have an idea? I've been fighting with this for hours and my thinking process has just come to an end.

Comment: It's customary not to substantially change the question after you've been given a helpful answer.  If you have a new question about executing on pagination, please mark this as correct, then ask that as a separate question.  Otherwise, we you might find yourself going back and forth on this for too long, and the exchange no longer becomes helpful to other readers.